# How to resolve the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime package issues in Visual Studio 2017 professional in Windows Machine?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting below error when i try to deploy the application into Emulator below package is asking after i added to mu Droid project. again it is asking to install .how to resolve this issue in visualstudio 4.6.1.0 version

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Can not resolve reference: System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, referenced by System.Reactive. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, or remove the reference to System.Reactive. Aria.Droid

Could you please provide the solution quickly......

Comment: Have you tried `add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`? Here is a similar problem you can refer: [error-system-runtime-interopservices-windowsruntime](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124731/error-system-runtime-interopservices-windowsruntime)

Comment: Yes i tried But not yet resolved ... is there any alternate way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You tried and get the same error?

Comment: its resolved ... issue is with Visual Studio professional 2017

Comment: for this issue we need to install Visual studio 2017 professional 15.8.6 then no need to install the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime package...